# Append Fields in an Existing ADO Recordset

Tags: excel, vba, append, clone, recordset

I am using an ADO recordset in Excel to grab a huge CSV (~1 million rows) and use it as External data to create a PivotCache & Pivottable.

I want to edit the recordset to append additional fields (columns) and add data that is calculated from one of the fields viz a week field which has string data like this:

e.g. if A, B, C are the recordset fields,

```
    A         B        C        D        E
w 2011 01                       01    2011
w 2011 02                       02    2011
w 2011 03                       03    2011
w 2011 04                       04    2011
w 2012 05                       05    2012
```

then I want to append fields D, E and add data to them as shown above, stripped from column A like I would do in excel,

D = VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))
E = VALUE(MID(A2,3,4))

but I want to do using SQL functions.

then I use this appended recordset to create a pivotcache and a pivottable using it as an external datasource.SEE MY COMMENTS IN THE CODE.i cannot clone the recordset into a new recordset also as its giving me some bookmarks not available error.

the following gives me errors:

```
Option Explicit 

Sub GetCSV() 
Application.EnableEvents = False 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

Dim sFileName As String 
Dim sFilePath As String 
Dim rngPivotDest As Range 
Dim pcPivotCache As PivotCache 
Dim ptPivotTable As PivotTable 
Dim SQL As String 
Dim sConnStrP1 As String 
Dim sConnStrP2 As String 
Dim cConnection As Object 
Dim rsRecordset As Object, RS As Object, Fld As Object 
Dim Sht As Worksheet 
Dim Conn As Object 

With ThisWorkbook 

Set rsRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
Set cConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 


sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files, *.asc; *.txt; *.csv", 1, "Select a      Text File", , False) 
sFilePath = Left(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, "\")) 
sFileName = Replace(sFileName, sFilePath, "") 

sConnStrP1 = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" 
sConnStrP2 = ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;FIL=text;Persist Security Info=False" 

cConnection.Open sConnStrP1 & sFilePath & sConnStrP2 
SQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & sFileName & "]" 
Set rsRecordset = cConnection.Execute(SQL) 


'****** THIS ENTIRE PART IS NOT WORKING****** 
With RS 
.cursorlocation = 3 'aduseclient 
.cursortype = 2 'adOpenDynamic 3 'adopenstatic 
'    For Each Fld In rsRecordset.Fields 
'        .Fields.append Fld.Name, Fld.Type, Fld.definedsize, Fld.Attributes,     Fld.adFldIsNullable 
'    Next Fld 
.locktype = 4 'adLockBatchOptimistic'3 'adlockoptimistic 
.Fields.append "WeekNumber", 3 'adinteger 
.Fields.append "Year", 7 'addate 

.Open 
.Update 

'do something to grab the entire data into RS 
Set RS = rsRecordset.Clone 

'or something like 
Set RS = rsRecordset.getrows 

'append some function code to the last 2 fields to strip YEAR & WEEK from 1st field. 
...... 
...... 


End With 
********************************* 

'Delete any connections in workbook 
On Error Resume Next 
For Each Conn In .Connections 
    Conn.Delete 
Next Conn 
On Error GoTo 0 

'Delete the Pivot Sheet 
On Error Resume Next 
For Each Sht In .Sheets 
If LCase(Trim(Sht.Name)) = LCase("Pivot") Then Sht.Delete 
Next Sht 
On Error GoTo 0 

'Create a PivotCache 
Set pcPivotCache = .PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal) 
Set pcPivotCache.Recordset = rsRecordset 

'Create a Pivot Sheet 
.Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets("Main") 
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot" 

'Create a PivotTable 
Set ptPivotTable =  pcPivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=.Sheets("Pivot").Range("A3")) 

With ptPivotTable 
    .Name = "PivotTable" 
    .SaveData = False 
End With 


With ptPivotTable 
    With .PivotFields("Level") 
       .Orientation = xlPageField 
       .Position = 1 
    End With 
With .PivotFields("Cat") 
    .Orientation = xlPageField 
    .Position = 1 
End With 
With .PivotFields("Mfgr") 
    .Orientation = xlPageField 
    .Position = 1 
End With 
With .PivotFields("Brand") 
    .Orientation = xlPageField 
    .Position = 1 
End With 
With .PivotFields("Descr") 
    .Orientation = xlRowField 
    .Position = 1 
End With 
End With 

ptPivotTable.AddDataField ptPivotTable.PivotFields("Sales Value from CrossCountrySales"), "Sum of Sales Value from CrossCountrySales", xlSum 

With ptPivotTable.PivotFields("Week") 
    .Orientation = xlColumnField 
    .Position = 1 
End With 

With ptPivotTable.PivotFields("Sum of Sales Value from CrossCountrySales") 
    .Calculation = xlNoAdditionalCalculation 
End With 

cConnection.Close 
Set rsRecordset = Nothing 
Set cConnection = Nothing 
Set Conn = Nothing 

End With 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
Application.EnableEvents = True 

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried creating and populating those additional columns in your SQL query, instead of adding them after?

Comment: hi Tim, i dont know how to add those columns and their extracted data via sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create those new fields in your original SQL query.

Here's a simplified example: I'm querying a txt file "week.txt" (which just has one column with header "week" and a few rows of test data) and dropping the recordset onto a worksheet.

```
Sub GetCSV()

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim sConnStrP1 As String
    Dim cConnection As Object
    Dim rsRecordset As Object, RS As Object
    Dim Conn As Object, i As Integer

    Set rsRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set cConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    sConnStrP1 = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
                 "Dbq=C:\_Stuff\test\" & _
                 ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;FIL=text;Persist Security Info=False"

    cConnection.Open sConnStrP1

    'create new columns based on "week" column
    '  1*(....) coerces to number
    SQL = "SELECT [week], 1*(right(week,2)) as wk_num, 1*(mid(week,3,4)) as year FROM [week.txt]"

    Set rsRecordset = cConnection.Execute(SQL)

    'drop to sheet...
    With ActiveSheet.Range("D5")
        For i = 0 To rsRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
            .Offset(0, i).Value = rsRecordset.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        .Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rsRecordset
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: my sql query is selecting entire data from a CSV, which will later be used to create a pivot table. i dont see you selecting the csv data, but you have only defined a select query to query the week column and create year and weeknumber columns. i am not dropping any data to worksheet, but creating an external pivotcache and using it to create a pivot table. the reason i was not appending columns to the source csv, because it is ~1 million rows and i dont know how to do it. i want the additional weeknumber and year columns in the recordset so that they appear and can be used in the pivottable.

Comment: Thanks Tim, editing the SQL query worked.     SQL = "SELECT *, [week], 1*(right(week,2)) as WeekNumber, 1*(mid(week,3,4)) as Year FROM [" & sFileName & "]" '[week.txt]"

Comment: Glad you got it working - my example was just to illustrate the general approach: I know you're doing something different with your dataset.

Comment: Yes, i have launch product sales data for 3 yrs i.e. spanning 156 weeks, which i want to somehow place properly within 52 weeks only as the idea is that a new product once launched will only run for not more than 52 weeks. there may be blanks (gaps i.e no sales) in between some weeks, but the total count of sales weeks will not exceed 52 weeks in 3 yrs. the logic is that any product sales starting from beginning week i.e. w 2011 01 but total sales weeks count <52 then it means it was launched previous year, so some sales  weeks are lying in previous year.

Comment: In such a scenario, this entire sales weeks are shifted to start from the week column: 52-Count of sales weeks +1. Any ideas on how to implement this in the SQL query as another column called say 'New Week'?

Comment: Not sure I follow you exactly, but you could create a "cumulative weeks" column: if you know the first year of your data then `cum_wks = (year-year_1)*12 + wk_num`  If you can share some dummy sample data with expected outcome, that would be helpful.

Comment: i have posted here including a screenshot of what i want. If you can share your email i can send you a sample file.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825905/shifting-156-weeks-sales-figures-to-52-weeks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54298/discussion-between-sifar786-and-tim-williams).

Comment: I'm disappointed.  Solved this user's problem, but didn't answer the question he asked.  I need the original question answered! Why didn't `Fields.Append` work? :-p

Comment: Some things just aren't supported?  Why they're not supported is another question, but not one that typically gets much traction here 'cause who really knows?